# How to install sudo on Alpine 3.17 VM?

Tags: sudo, virtual-machine, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I have installed Alpine r3.17 on a VM under KVM.  I want to install `sudo` tool.

```
# su -
# apk update
   ... 
OKL 4994 distinct packages available
# apk add sudo 
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  sudo (no such package):
    required by: world[sudo]
```

After checking the Alpine website, I see `sudo` is a valid package:

- [Alpine packages -`sudo`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.17/community/x86_64/sudo)

Valid for release 3.17.  I've seen similar questions on the web for r3.16 as well, so I don't think this is a new problem.  And yes for a virtul machine, not a container, I do want sudo on key machines.

Yet `apk` does not find it.  Everywhere I have looked so far show an install command like:

```
# apk add sudo
```

For example:

- [Post Installation Recommendations](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/post-install.html), [Alpine user handbook](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook)
- [Add, Delete And Grant Sudo Privileges To Users In Alpine Linux](https://ostechnix.com/add-delete-and-grant-sudo-privileges-to-users-in-alpine-linux/)
- [QEMU](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/QEMU), [Alpine Linux wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki)

  - Shows `sudo` usage, but not how it was installed.

I wondered if '*world*' is relevant, as in: "`required by: world[sudo]`"?  Do I need to explicitly reference another repository.  According to the package docs `sudo` is in "community".  Additionally, the package: `spice-vdagent` is not found for installation, but I was able to install `spice-0.15.1`.

The problem is not unique to the `sudo` utility.  Any useful advice is welcome.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In /etc/apk/repositories the community repo is commented out.  The sudo and a lot of other packages are in that repo.

```
sed -i 's/#\(.*\/community\)/\1/' /etc/apk/repositories
```